# Missing Mutual TLS Reference in Identity Server

Tags: ssl, jwt, certificate, identityserver4, tls1.2

Good Afternoon,

I've been following the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html) for adding mutual TLS to Identity Server.

However, when I add the following code:

```
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.MutualTls.Enabled = true;
        options.MutualTls.ClientCertificateAuthenticationScheme = "x509";
    });
```

I get this import reference error:

> 'Identity Server Options' does not contain a definition for 'MutualTls'...

It's the same for `AddMutualTlsSecretValidators`.

Are those references in a separate library? I scoured the documentation and have been digging around for a while but can't seem to find anything.

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

I tried various imports in my Startup class such as IdentityModel, idunno.Authentication.Certificate and IdentityServer4 but those didn't help.

Here's my Startup class:

```
using IdentityModel;
using idunno.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCertificate("x509", options =>
                {
                    options.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

                    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnValidateCertificate = context =>
                        {
                            context.Principal = Principal.CreateFromCertificate(context.ClientCertificate, includeAllClaims: true);
                            context.Success();

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                // Complains about missing reference
                options.MutualTls.Enabled = true;
                // Complains about missing reference
                options.MutualTls.ClientCertificateAuthenticationScheme = "x509";

            })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            // Complains about missing reference
            .AddMutualTlsSecretValidators();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a new feature. You may have to upgrade the used package of IdentityServer.

Comment: Looks like that was it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ruard van Elburg said, looks like my version of Identity Server 4 was not the most current. When I updated to the latest (2.5.0) it worked.